# Motor tripping GFCI

Tags: gfci

I have a 1HP 3-phase motor hooked up to a variable speed controller and phase converter which uses standard 120V household current. However, when the motor is turned on it invariably trips the GFCI interrupts on the circuit. I can have an electrician come in and remove the GFCI breakers on the circuit, but before going to the expense of doing this, is there any other option?

Comment: Why was this device on the GFCI circuit, is there a known safety issue? Are there other devices on the same circuit that require GFCI protection?  If the connection is outdoors or near a wet location your local electrical code likely requires a GFCI breaker. I would recommend first finding and correcting the cause of the breaker tripping instead of just replacing the GFCI. The breaker tripped for a reason.

Comment: Is it the motor or the VFD that trips the GFCI? Try some tests, use a known good load.

Comment: @Bryan I don't want to disconnect the VFD from the motor because it is hard-wired. My engineer tells me that GFCIs "do not like" big motors.

Comment: @Bryan now that I think about, it has to be the motor because the motor runs briefly before tripping the GFCI. If it was a cable issue or the VFD, then it would probably cut out immediately.

Comment: Well my first thought is that the motor isn’t rated for VFD operation and the high frequency is leaking out from the windings to the protective earth, tripping the GFCI. If you have the option to lower your inverter frequency that may help a little if my suspicion is correct.